# Can I have a NSURLSession delegate method in a different ViewController in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I am using iOS7 and Xcode 5.

I have instantiated a NSURLSession object with a URL in one ViewController and then I want to write its delegate in a different ViewController. Is it possible?

Basically, I want to make the call in one ViewController, and immediately after making the call I transit to the other ViewController. Once the transition is made, I want to receive the response in the second ViewController through the NSURLSession delegate methods and then display the data. Is this possible?

Note: I don't want to keep the user waiting in the first ViewController until the server comes back with its response, because while the server is processing the data, I can keep the user engaged in the second ViewController with other images/elements displayed.

Comment: Why dont you make a api class of nsobject type of your self and use blocks to get data when server gets back with responce?

Comment: Hi Amar, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why don't you just push the next view controller on first, then make the data request in that second view controller after it has loaded?

Comment: I have a Social Media log in button on the first screen - so once the user clicks log in button, the request to the server is sent, the push to the next view controller is made, and then the response from server is waited in the second screen. Any better way to accomplish this? :)

Comment: @Zhang I'd suggest you expand upon that and put that as an answer. We could advise Abhishek in all sorts of elegant solutions that allows him to have the second view controller handle the server response of a request initiated by the first view controller, but on the basis of what's been shared so far, your suggestion seems like the simplest and most logical approach.

Comment: @Zhang, your solution sounds to be the simplest and most efficient way to implement it. I am going to try it now.

Comment: In big projects i dont like handling url delegates in view controller i keep it separate from the class from which i am initiating the request

Comment: @Amar that is a good point. What was the approach you used then as an alternate? In this situation, how would you have approached it and where separately would you keep the calls and delegate?

Comment: I subclass afnetworking and use my own blocks..

Answer (score 0):

Your Api.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef void(^successTypeBlock)(NSData*);
typedef void(^errorTypeBlock)(NSError*);
@interface TestApi : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate>

-(void)hitApiWithURL:(NSURL*)url successBlock:(successTypeBlock)success  failureBlock:(errorTypeBlock)failure;
@end
```

your Api.m

```
@interface  TestApi()
{

}
@property(nonatomic,copy) errorTypeBlock    errorBlock_;
@property(nonatomic,copy) successTypeBlock  successBlock_;
@end
@implementation TestApi


-(void)hitApiWithURL:(NSURL*)url successBlock:(successTypeBlock)success  failureBlock:(errorTypeBlock)failure{
    errorBlock_=failure;
    successBlock_=success;
    NSURLRequest   *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{
    successBlock_(data);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{



}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    errorBlock_(error);
}



@end
```

Now

```
[<yourApiObj>   hitApiWithURL:<your URL> successBlock:^(NSData* data){
//get success value here after server responce

}  failureBlock:^(NSError* error){

//get error if any
}];
```

just gave you a basic skeleton improve and innovate as per your needs.

Comment: Hi Amar, I am using iOS 7 and it supports NSURLSession rather than NSURLConnection.

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar Its a generic structure use it with any thing ... it explains how to get callbacks using blocks..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it on the main thread
I think you need use threading concept so that, you can accomplish this using the secondary thread. And even the UI will not get blocked.

Write a class and subclass it with NSOperation.

refer this

1. Apple's Sample code : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NSOperationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004184
2. Refer this wonderfull tutorial. 
   http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Hope this will help you.